# sql insert rows from another table based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following two tables

Table 1

```
ID    DATA
1      'A'
2      'B'
3      'C'
4      'D'
5      'E'
6      'F'
```

Table 2

```
ID    DATA
2       'G'
3       'F'
4       'Q'
```

How do I insert data into Table 1 from Table 2 where Table 2 doesn't have Table 1's ID?

In other words, I'd like the following result:

Table 2

```
ID    DATA
1       'A'
2       'G'
3       'F'
4       'Q'
5       'E'
6       'F'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wording in your question a little bit confusing because you first ask *How do I insert data into* ***Table 1*** *from Table 2* but then you're showing the desired result for ***Table2***.

Now if you want to insert rows from table1 into table2 with `id`s that doesn't exist in table2 you can do it this way

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (id, data)
SELECT id, data
  FROM Table1 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM Table2
   WHERE id = t.id
)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbbcd/2)** demo

or

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (id, data)
SELECT t1.id, t1.data
  FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27535/1)** demo

Outcome (in both cases):

```
| ID | DATA |
|----|------|
|  1 |    A |
|  2 |    G |
|  3 |    F |
|  4 |    Q |
|  5 |    E |
|  6 |    F |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, DATA)
SELECT a.ID, a.DATA 
FROM Table1 a
JOIN (
        SELECT ID FROM Table1
        EXCEPT
        SELECT ID FROM Table2
    ) b
    ON b.ID = a.ID
;
```

Here some code you can run in SSMS that will exemplify this code by:

- Setting up temp tables
- Filling the temp tables with data (taken from peterm's SQL Fiddle however heavily modified)
- Executing the above
- Then cleaning up after itself by destroying the temp tables

.

```
PRINT 'Dropping and creating temp tables';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t1;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t2;

CREATE TABLE #t1 (
    ID INT, DATA VARCHAR(1)
);

CREATE TABLE #t2 (
    ID INT, DATA VARCHAR(1))
;

PRINT 'Temp tables created';
PRINT 'Inserting test data into temp tables';

INSERT INTO #t1 (
    ID, DATA
)
VALUES
     (1, 'A')
    ,(2, 'B')
    ,(3, 'C')
    ,(4, 'D')
    ,(5, 'E')
    ,(6, 'F')
;


INSERT INTO #t2 (
    ID, DATA
) 
VALUES
     (2, 'G')
    ,(3, 'F')
    ,(4, 'Q')
;

PRINT 'Test data inserted';
PRINT 'SELECTING temp tables before modifying data'


SELECT * FROM #t1;
SELECT * FROM #t2;

PRINT 'Modifying data'

INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, DATA)
SELECT a.ID, a.DATA 
FROM #t1 a
JOIN (
        SELECT ID FROM #t1
        EXCEPT
        SELECT ID FROM #t2
    ) b
    ON b.ID = a.ID
;

PRINT 'SELECTING "after" modifying data'

SELECT * FROM #t1
SELECT * FROM #t2

PRINT 'Cleaning up (destroying temp tables)'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t1;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t2;
```